# As a renter, do I need the Dutch energy label for anything?

Tags: netherlands, rental

I'm moving to the Netherlands, and am arranging contracts etc with a rental agency. They say that an Energy label/energy performance certificate is "not available". My understanding is that the owner is legally required to provide one (https://www.government.nl/topics/energy-performance-certificates-for-homes-and-buildings/epcs-for-buyers-and-tenants), but I'm not going to push super hard unless I have a specific need for it for something else (energy provider, local authority, etc.). Do I need it?

Comment: If you have all inclusive contract I would say you don't need it

Comment: With energy label, you can calculate/estimate spendings on the warming the house (recently cooling also becomes important)

Comment: @EugenMartynov If all inclusive means paying for Gas/Electricity/Water, then I don't have that.

Comment: If you try insisting that you're provided with an EPC - please report back on this page what eventually happened.

Answer (score 2):

Tenants do not really need this certificate for anything, I certainly never had to present it anywhere. But this is presumably designed to enable you to make an informed decision when moving in. An accommodation with poor energy efficiency could cost you tens of euros a month down the line. And refusing to provide one might suggest the landlord is trying to hide the fact that his property is not terribly attractive from that point of view.

Even with a contract covering energy costs, you have to read the fine print, I once had such a contract but the monthly payments were only provisions to be adjusted at the end of the year, when I was it with a €1500 bill for heating for a rather small apartment.

Comment: Gala, you're right. I forgot and I was in the same situation and had to pay extra burned because of the apartment was cold. And it is not pleasant thing and it was a quite significant sum of money

Comment: "Refusing to provide one etc." - In many places, an energy rating has never been calculated and landlords might simply not think they should be bothered to bring some specialist in to do that.

Comment: @einpoklum Same difference. [It does not require to “bring in” an expert](https://www.government.nl/topics/energy-performance-certificates-for-homes-and-buildings/epcs-for-homeowners), it's done online. I am sure there are also landlords who “think” they should not be “bothered” with renovations, smoke detectors and what not but that's the law and it's there for a reason.

Comment: And those landlords who don't have the definitive energy rating at hand in the first place are probably more likely than not to have a poorly isolated property too. Many years after this was introduced EU-wide, they are actively refusing to comply at this point.